# AWS Athena: does `msck repair table` incur costs?

Tags: hive, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I have ORC data in S3 that looks like this:

```
s3://bucket/orc/clientId=client-1/year=2017/month=3/day=16/hour=20/
s3://bucket/orc/clientId=client-2/year=2017/month=3/day=16/hour=21/
s3://bucket/orc/clientId=client-3/year=2017/month=3/day=16/hour=22/
```

Every hour I run an EMR job that converts raw JSON in S3 to ORC, and write it out with the path partition convention (above) for Athena ingestion. After the EMR job completes, I run `msck repair table` so Athena can pick up the new partitions.

I have 3 related questions:

1. Does running `msck repair table` in this scenario, cost me money in AWS?
2. [AWS Docs say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl/msck-repair-table.html) `msck repair table` can timeout.  Is there a way I can make a step in data pipeline to continue running this command until it completes successfully?
3. I would prefer to add the partitions manually to Athena (since I know the year,month,day,hour I'm working on).  However I do not know the `clientId` because there could be 1-X of them, and I don't know which ones exist at time of running EMR.  Is there a best practice way to solve this problem (using Hive or something else)? I could make an s3 api call to get a list of `s3://bucket/org/` and write code to iterate over list and add manually. I'm hoping there is an easier way...

Note: when I say "add partitions manually" I mean doing something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <athena table> 
ADD PARTITION (clientId='client-1',year=2017,month=3,day=16,hour=20) 
location 's3://bucket/orc/clientId=client-1/year=2017/month=3/day=16/hour=20/';
```

Answer (score 5):

[AWS says](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=755413&#755413):

> There's no charge for DDL queries or for partition detection.

[AWS says](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=773528):

> S3 GET charges do apply.

I do not yet know how to automate `msck repair table` to make sure it completes.